# projects merge automatically when adding a new project to the solution in jetbrains rider

Tags: ide, rider

I am working on a project in rider IDE I currently have one web API project in it when I try to add a new project to the solution rider adds the new project to the already existing web API project directory. This causes an error because there are two program.cs files in the web API project
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9XHs.png)

[adding a new project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nb5vQ.png)

[after adding the new project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdd3r.png)

Comment: Do you have placed both solution and project in the same directory? If yes, move the project to a subfolder